# Multi Platform Nuget using VSO

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to automate the generation of the following NuGet package using VSO:
[NuGet Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0btq3.png)

My problem is that all three "runtimes" libraries are built on different platforms. Hence, I have the following build configuration in VSO:
[VSO Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnnaB.png)

When build is completed, each agent job publish a native artifact for its platform:
[Native Artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg8Vz.png)

My question is: Is it possible to add a 4th agent job to the build that would wait for all the other jobs and then aggregate the artifacts and generate the NuGet package with everything?

Currently, I need to manually download the artifacts and run a script to pack and sign the NuGet package. It's annoying because it require to install a certificate on my local machine and install the signing tools etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for the "Run this Job" setting on the 4th agent job. "Only When all previous jobs are complete" sounds like the value you want. You could then use powershell and/or the NuGet task to automate your process.

Comment: How would I retrieve the artifacts built by the other jobs? Is their a built-in solution or do I need to upload these artifacts to an external server then download them from the 4th agent job?

Comment: You put them in azure blob storage somewhere or you could use the REST API to download the published artifacts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/artifacts?view=vsts-rest-5.0